How to cross-compile GDAL for aarch64-linux-gnu?
I am working on running Rust on a ZCU106 devkit (ARM64), where I'm using the GDAL crate. The Rust crate compiles fine but needs to be linked to the compiled binaries of the GDAL library in C. The compiled binaries are for x86_64 architecture, hence I need to compile the library from source, for aarch64-linux-gnu. To do this, I created a build directory, and wrote the following toolchain file (toolchain_file.cmake):
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

Then I ran the command: cmake ../gdal/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain_file.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.
Resulted in the error:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find PROJ (missing: PROJ_LIBRARY) (found version "8.2.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/packages/FindPROJ.cmake:57 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/helpers/CheckDependentLibraries.cmake:399 (find_package)
  gdal.cmake:266 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:240 (include)

It seems I am missing the following packages:
-- Could NOT find ODBC (missing: ODBC_LIBRARY ODBCINST) 
-- Could NOT find ODBCCPP (missing: ODBCCPP_LIBRARY ODBCCPP_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find MSSQL_ODBC (missing: MSSQL_ODBC_LIBRARY MSSQL_ODBC_INCLUDE_DIR MSSQL_ODBC_VERSION) 
-- Could NOT find MySQL (missing: MYSQL_LIBRARY) (found version "8.0.36")
-- Could NOT find Iconv (missing: Iconv_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_DIR)
-- Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_LIBRARY) (found version "3.2.3")
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
-- Could NOT find Deflate (missing: Deflate_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find CryptoPP (missing: CRYPTOPP_LIBRARY CRYPTOPP_TEST_KNOWNBUG CRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find PROJ (missing: PROJ_DIR)

To fix this, I downloaded the PROJ source code and wrote the same toolchain_file.cmake in a different directory, and ran: cmake ../proj-9.4.0/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain_file.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.
This resulted in:
-- nlohmann/json: internal
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:202 (message):
  sqlite3 binary not found!


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find SQLite3 (missing: SQLite3_LIBRARY) (found version "3.37.2")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindSQLite3.cmake:54 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:215 (find_package)

How do I fix this? Is there a better way to cross-compile this? As of now I will have to build every dependency from source and cross-compile that.

Where is the GDAL library on your target system gonna come from? If you're linking statically, then yes, you need every single dependency in the chain, no way around that. But if you're doing dynamic linking, then you can just grab your direct dependencies from the package mirror, extract them to some folder, and pass that to the compiler/linker.

The dynamically linked library is located in: /lib/libgdal.so.30.0.3. The output of file /lib/libgdal.so.30.0.3 gives: /lib/libgdal.so.30.0.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5ba0c0ac9cd7487c3c360d2ca8666c6902ece08a, stripped which means it is compiled for the x86_64 architecture only, not aarch64. So won't I have to build from source and compile again?

I'm talking about your target machine, the arm64 one. Where does it get libgdal from?

I haven't added the libraries to the target yet. But whatever cross-compiled binary (building from source) I use to build it on my host, I'll add it to the target as well.
